# Ubuntu 18.04 missing 'Global Dark Theme' Option in GNOME Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

My GNOME Ubuntu 16.04 had this option under the tweaks tool:

`Tweaks > Appearance > Global Dark Theme > On/Off`

My same setup on 18.04 is simply missing this option entirely. How do I get the on/off button back? There's not even this `Global Dark Theme` line item under `Appearances` at all.

Comment: I found out how to set this missing option manually by editing the GTK configuration files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably look for the Adwaita-dark theme

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'
```

you will also find a Firefox Extension to make it dark too
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adwaita-dark/

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works, how can i get system back to default theme?

Comment: @jerry: To get back to the default theme use `$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'`

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer a gui based solution, install gnome-tweaks:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

and invoke it with

```
gnome-tweaks&
```

or your system menu.

Under the menu **appearance** you can choose in **Themes - Applications** different themes, e.g. Adwaita-dark.

Other themes can be found on the [**gnome-look**](https://www.gnome-look.org/) web page. First create a theme directory `mkdir ~/.themes`and download your theme into this directory. Then open again tweak tools and choose under the appearance the theme you like most. There are really cool themes, like macos, win10, or even other themes there.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04, there used to be a dedicated gnome-tweak-tool option for "global dark theme" or something like that. This option is missing on newer versions. However, I figured out how to set this old feature manually as my old Unity GTK settings (from 16.04) are still in place for my main user.

The GTK configuration files are located at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and `~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini`.

Make sure the files contains the following:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

I believe the default is zero. Log out and log back in to apply the changes.